# Validate Input in Codeigniter for security and space alphanumeric and specific characters

Tags: regex, codeigniter, validation

Being bad at `Regex` and New to `Codeigniter`, I need help in validating input for security (XSS, injection, etc) and keep it limited to alphanumeric, spaces, and characters like . @, # ( ) [ ]

No other characters should be allowed.
The valid string would look like (sequence of characters does not matter, any valid character or alphabet or number can be present anywhere in the string):

> [Wave] Hello, Id No. 123 registered as bol@gmail.com (nickname bol
>   roy)

I have written following code in Controller:

```
public function _titleRegex($data) 
{
    if(preg_match('/^[][a-zA-Z0-9@# ,().]+$/',$data))
    {
        return TRUE;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Some invalid characters are present.</div>";
        //Also tried return FALSE; still I get the same error
    }
}

public function addproperty()
{
        $msg="";
        $config = array(
            array(
                    'field' => 'categories',
                    'label' =>'Category',
                    'rules' => 'required'
            ),
            array(
                'field'=>'ptitle',
                'label'=>'Property Title',
                'rules'=>'trim|required|xss_clean|callback__titleRegex'
            )
        );
       $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
       if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
       { 
        return validation_errors();
       } 
       else 
       {
//do the work and then the further code ........
```

On running the page, I get the following error:

> Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Property Title.(_titleRegex)

Please help

Comment: They guy who marked this question negative, I request you to please provide me the reason for this

Comment: Did you take a look at [character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)?

Comment: @Thefourthbird As I wrote that I am new to Codeigniter and bad at Regex so couldn't compile the answers already available to a solution for my problem, that's why I posted this question here without any code

Comment: If you want to match the character in the character class, you could update your regex to `^[][a-zA-Z0-9@ ,().]+$` and place matching the opening and closing square brackets right after the opening one https://regex101.com/r/06L5VH/1.

Comment: The valid string would look like:   [Wave] Hello, Id No. 123 registered as bol@gmail.com (nickname bol roy)

Comment: It does right? https://regex101.com/r/06L5VH/2 See the [PHP test](https://3v4l.org/1jEpY)

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yeah, it worked, Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to the reply my Me. @Thefourthbird, following can help you out:

```
array(
    'field'=>'ptitle',
    'label'=>'Property Title',
    'rules'=>'trim|required|xss_clean|regex_match[/^[][a-zA-Z0-9@# ,().]+$/]'
)
```